# Is there a way to update Windows 10 on several notebooks from offline?

Tags: windows-10, auto-update

I have several laptops in my organization. When I need to give out them to users, they, of couse, start update Windows 10. Is there a way to keep them up to date and update them when they're in the laptop charging trolley? I mean is there a way I can automatically power them on when they're in charging trolley and they're turned off, then automatically log in local account, automatically update them, restart them if it needed and automatically turn them off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the below:

1. Use some program to wake the laptop (Wake up from LAN) once there is data initialize.
2. Use GPO settings to call for Window update from a offline WSUS server & restart when required.
3. Task scheduler to do the shutdown.